# Custom Taxonomy Page

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm trying to create a page that shows all the subcategories of a specific category. So in context, I have a Parent Category titled 'Destinations'. I'd like to be able to click on Destinations and be led to a page showing a list of the subcategories or Countries. Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve minus the map at the top -  https://www.vagabrothers.com/destinations.

In the ideal world, the Category page would have the same layout as this page. You can see what I mean from the example above.

It would make the navigation on the site like this Destinations > Country > Individual Post.

I'm using CPT UI and have set up a custom post type and categories called 'Destinations' and then have a bunch of sub-categories of the countries.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the hierarchy of WordPress templates, you can create a template: `category-$slug.php`, in your case, it will be: `category-destinations.php` (to mention that the slug must be the same name) .

So this template will have the priority if we click on the link category destinations.

> I used Twenty Nineteen theme.

Templete named : `category-destinations.php`

```
get_header();
?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main">
                <?php
                $subcat = get_categories(array(
                    'orderby' => 'name',
                    'parent' => $wp_query->queried_object->term_id
                ));
                if (count($subcat)):
                foreach ($subcat as $key => $value) {
                    echo '<h2>' . $value->name .'</h2>';
                    echo '<a title="'.$value->name.'" '
                            . 'href="' . esc_url(get_category_link($value->term_id)) .'">'
                            .esc_html($value->cat_name,"twentynineteen").'</a>';
                }
                else :
                    esc_html__("No subcategories found","twentynineteen");
                endif;
    ?>
    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

I created a Destination category, and I added: Aciform, arrangement, ..... as a subcategory and the relults :

[image]

Here I have recovered that the name and the links of the category. if you want to add an image to the subcategory, you need a custom code, because WordPress by default does not offer the possibility of adding images for the category.

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back to me. Can you give me an example of what the code might look like in total? I created a category-destinations.php and added the code. This is what I've got 

get_header(); ?>

<h1>Test</h1>

<p><?php 
$subcat = get_categories(array(                    
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'parent' => $wp_query->queried_object->term_id
));
?></p>

<p><?php echo ' . $subcat . ';?></p>

<?php get_footer(); ?>

Comment: ok done. I updated the code. to test the code: 1 - create a template named: `category-destinations.php`, 2- create a category slug `destinations`, 3 - Add subcategories for Destinations.